# C# - Checkbox's CheckChanged Event Has Wrong Checked State

Tags: c#, events, checkbox, status, checked

I'm working on a Windows form which should enable / disable some controls based on a checkbox's checked status.  To watch for this, there is an event handler for the CheckedChanged event.  This has worked for other forms just fine, with the same exact code, but it is not working correctly here.  Whether the checkbox is being checked or unchecked, the checked state is always false.  Here's the code:

```
    private void chkDisable_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkDisable.Checked)
        {
            DisableFormFields();
        }
        else
        {
            EnableFormFields();
        }
    }
```

Like I said, this exact code works fine in one form -- the Checked state is correctly set to true or false based on what you just changed it to.  But in the new form, the Checked state is always false in that method, whether it is being checked or unchecked.  The event fires fine, and hits the breakpoint I set in the method, but the Checked state never changes.  Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the name of the checkbox you want to check? Even if it triggers the right event handler maybe you are testing the wrong control (chkDisable)?

Comment: Try using CheckBox.CheckState property:     If(chkDisable.CheckState==CheckState.Checked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
private void chkDisable_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
            DisableFormFields();
        }
        else
        {
            EnableFormFields();
        }
}
```

Comment: Agree, but i think problem was in wrong link to chkDisable. Look he stop on breakpoint in that code, so he applied event to correct checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, that got it.  I'm still annoyed that the same code I used in a different form doesn't work here, but for now I'm just glad to get past this problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check that your eventHandler `chkDisable_CheckedChanged` is applied to correct checkBox i.e. to `chkDisable` checkbox.

If still the problem persits, **delete** and **re-drag** the checkbox control and **apply the event**.

Applying casting and shortcut should not be the correct methodology to solve a problem (This is what I personally think.)

Comment: @Alessa: No :) .. Its most sane mistake. :P

Comment: Nope, not the issue.  Like I said in my post, the event fires and goes to the correct method.  I also did double-check that the right checkbox is using the right method before posting.  EDIT: the answer by Likurg worked correctly.

Comment: @Greg: I think you must delete and re-drag the control again. To get the output with same code and without casting.